# Are there two answers to this integral problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

I got a test back and got a problem wrong, but I did some research and I think I may have a case. Just wanted to run it  by some professionals to see what you guys think.

Here is the problem and my professors answer:
http://i49.tinypic.com/1ijwwg.png

I got something else because I did the area under instead of above.

Is that allowed? Did my professor write a problem that could have two answers?

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you rotated about the x-axis instead of the y-axis? There is only 1 (final) answer to these kinds of problems. The only time when you have a case, is when both of your answers are numerically the same.

Comment: @CalvinLin thats what I thought. But when I asked an online tutor about the problem, he said that it was poorly writen because you can rotate around the y-axis but still have a curve above or something like that.

Comment: No, I'm not sure who you spoke to. Why don't you also include your work, and then ask if you are correct. That would be much preferred in this community (showing your work).

Comment: Please copy the problem and professors' answer here for later reference, the link could break at any time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is only $1$ answer.

You say you calculated the area under instead of above, but the problem asks you to calculate *surface area*, there is no choice of under or above on that.  Did you take the area under the curve and rotate it to get a *volume of revolution*?  This is a common mistake.

In any case, go ask your instructor.  You probably wont get any points back but I'm sure they'll be happy to explain exactly what the mistake is.  Then you will be less likely to repeat the mistake on a future test.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one other reasonable answer.  Recall that the problem only asks us to *set up* an integral. But whatever answer (definite integral) we come up with, the numerical answer, once the integral is *evaluated*, will be the same.

In this case, it is actually quite natural to integrate with respect to $x$. Let $f(x)$ be our function. Then our surface area is equal to
$$\int_{x=3}^8 2\pi x\sqrt{1+(f'(x))^2}\,dx.$$
The sample solution instead sets up an integral with respect to $y$. This is perfectly correct, of course. The function we integrate then looks a little nicer (I don't like stuff in the denominator either) but setting it up is more work than mechanically differentiating $f(x)$.